# How to get the name of the day from java sql.Timestamp object?

Tags: java, timestamp

How to get the name of the day from `java sql.Timestamp` object such as Monday, Tuesday?

Comment: Check out the JodaTime library.  It makes date processing at least ten times simpler than java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You convert your java.sql.Timestamp to a java.sql.Date and send it through a Calendar.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(1);
java.util.GregorianCalendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(ts);
System.out.println(cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Comment: I think `Calendar.get()` returns an integer. So, this would mean you still have to create a representing string for the day of the week.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to construct a new date on it. The `Timestamp` is a **subclass** of `java.util.Date`. So `cal.setTime(ts)` would have worked as good. Further, the recommended practice is to obtain the calendar by its abstract factory as `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()`.

Comment: But it still does not show a string representation of the name of a day like `"Monday"`,`"Montag"`,`"Lundi"` etc. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

If `ts` is your `Timestamp` object then to get the month in string format:

```
String month = (new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM")).format(ts.getTime()); // "April"
```

and for the day of the week:

```
String day = (new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")).format(ts.getTime()); // "Tuesday"
```

Comment: dont use this!
cos SimpleDateFormat didn't measure timezone (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone/18124407#18124407)
but when you setting time from long, you don't know it timezone!

Comment: Any time represented in long is represented as number of milliseconds since epoch. This is UTC.

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will provide a [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) specific representation using the pattern `"EEEE"`:

```
 public static final String getDayName(final java.util.Date date, final java.util.Locale locale)
          {
           SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE",locale);
           return df.format(date);
          }
```

Example usage:

```
System.out.println(getDayName(new Date(),Locale.US));
```

returns `Tuesday`.

But beware that `new SimpleDateFormat(..)` is [expensive](http://www.thedwick.com/blog/2008/04/simpledateformat-performance-pig/).

Comment: dont use this! cos SimpleDateFormat didn't measure timezone (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone/18124407#18124407) but when you setting time from long, you don't know it timezone!

Comment: @AndriyAntonov So how does one get a month from `java.sql.Timestamp` correctly?