# Calendar timezone , how does it work?

Tags: java

When I execute the below snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone timeZoneInd = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
        TimeZone timeZoneAus = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Adelaide");

        Calendar calendarInd = Calendar.getInstance(timeZoneInd);
        Calendar calendarAus = Calendar.getInstance(timeZoneAus);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss SSSS");

        System.out.println("Australian time now :" + sdf.format(calendarAus.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Indian time now     :" + sdf.format(calendarInd.getTime()));

    }
```

Why is it that both values are same ? Should'nt each print time corresponding to its timezone ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat parse loses timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

That is because the time in each `Calendar` object is the same. If you want to format dates for different time zones, you will need to set the time zone in the format object, like this:

```
TimeZone timeZoneInd = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
TimeZone timeZoneAus = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Adelaide");

SimpleDateFormat formatInd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss SSSS");
formatInd.setTimeZone(timeZoneInd);
SimpleDateFormat formatAus = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss SSSS");
formatAus.setTimeZone(timeZoneAus);

Calendar calendarInd = Calendar.getInstance(timeZoneInd);
Calendar calendarAus = Calendar.getInstance(timeZoneAus);

System.out.println("Australian time now :" + formatAus.format(new Date()));
System.out.println("Indian time now     :" + formatInd.format(new Date()));

calendarAus.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendarInd.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);

System.out.println("Australian time at noon :" + formatAus.format(calendarAus.getTime()));
System.out.println("Indian time at noon     :" + formatInd.format(calendarInd.getTime()));
```

This for me gives the following output:

- Australian time now :20/02/2015-23:00:51 0081
- Indian time now     :20/02/2015-18:00:51 0082
- Australian time at noon  :20/02/2015-12:00:51 0081
- Indian time at noon      :20/02/2015-12:00:51 0081

You should use the `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting your dates, the `Calendar` object should be used for manipulating dates.

Comment: Strange !! A formatter should only format ... What does it have to do with Timezones? I was thinking that calendar.getTime() would return different Date objects based on their Timezones. Looks like its not the case !

Comment: I get it now, timezone need not be associated with calendar object at all, looks like just as System.currentTimeInMillis() Date objects are independent of Timezones. Thanks :)