# Confusion with Java Calendar and time zones

Tags: java

Consider the following code fragment...

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(c.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        Calendar gmtCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        System.out.println(gmtCal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
        System.out.println(gmtCal.getTime());
        System.out.println(gmtCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska"));
        System.out.println(c2.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
        System.out.println(c2.getTime());
        System.out.println(c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
Eastern Standard Time
Mon Jul 13 16:10:14 EDT 2015 
16
Greenwich Mean Time
Mon Jul 13 16:10:14 EDT 2015  //<--- also not sure why this isn't 4 hours ahead as Eastern time is UTC/GMT - 4 right now due to DST
20
Alaska Standard Time
Mon Jul 13 16:10:14 EDT 2015 //<--- date is not reflecting correct time and is showing EDT versus AST
12
```

Why does the `get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` method call not match the hour in the `getTime()` method call? Another way to put it, is why isn't this the output?

```
Eastern Standard Time
Mon Jul 13 16:10:14 EDT 2015
16
Greenwich Mean Time
Mon Jul 13 20:10:14 GMT 2015
20
Alaska Standard Time
Mon Jul 13 12:10:14 AST 2015
12
```

Edit...
So how can I get the following

```
long t = 1436842840327L;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(t);
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska"));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

to print the same hour as in `getTime()`? The output currently is

```
Mon Jul 13 23:00:40 EDT 2015
19:0:327
```

Comment: If you use `Java 8` you may want to work with [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [getTime()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_gettime.htm) returns a [Date object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and Date objects, when when converted to a string, are represented using your default time zone.

So by using getTime() you're getting a Date object that no longer contains the timezone data (a Date is just a specific point in time). Then that Date object gets implicitly converted to a string when it's printed.

Comment: @TryCatch You mean how to get it to work how you'd expect? I would look into using the SimpleDateFormat class, here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone

Answer (score 2):

Java doc clearly states for method [`getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29):

> *public static Calendar getInstance()*
>   Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is **based on the current time in the default time zone** with the default locale.

(emphasis mine)