# How to print a date in a specific time zone?

Tags: java, calendar

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393041/confusion-with-java-calendar-and-time-zones) question earlier, but am still not sure how to go about solving my problem. I am hoping to find the best way to set the time zone of a user and then extract the date in the users time zone (and not servers local time zone). Some code will clarify...(Note: this code is a simplification of my problem)

```
long t = 1436842840327L;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(t);
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska"));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

outputs

```
Mon Jul 13 23:00:40 EDT 2015
19:0:327 //<--- why is hour not 23???
```

But I want it to output

```
Mon Jul 13 23:00:40 EDT 2015
23:0:327
```

I have a web service that is provided a Calendar object based on the web users local time. I then need to process this Calendar object on the server side so I have to look up the users time zone in the database, set it and then extract the hour use in querying a database. What ends up happening is both the Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH and Calendar.HOUR do not match the date that the Calendar object represents. To summarize, I want the user to supply a Calendar object, set the time zone and then extract the correct hour and day.

Comment: The function getTime() returns a Date object, and Date objects, when when converted to a string, are represented using [your default time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31393107/300257).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you **MUST NOT** use `Calendar#toString` nor `Date#toString` to get a string representation of a date. Instead, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
Date yourDate = ...
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Alaska"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(yourDate));
```