# Working with UTC time in Java and .net?

Tags: java, datetime, utc

In my application, I'm reading a String value from a file which represents a time in UTC format and is generated by .net 2015. In my application which is in Java, I read this value and need to convert it into a long value first and then convert it back to a UTC time. Here is my code in Java to convert time to long value:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = df.parse(timeString);
long timeLong = date.getTime();
```

and to convert it back to UTC format:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = new Date(timeLong);               
newTimeStamp = df.format(date);
```

However, the final UTC time I get is not the same as the original time I read from file. It has almost two hours difference. I want to know whether it is because of the difference in implementation of time conversion in Java and .Net.

My original time is `2015-12-22T21:00:11.8701036Z` and the final time I get after doing this conversion is `2015-12-22T23:25:12.000036Z`.

p.s. I'm using Java 1.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat parse loses timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone)

Comment: I flagged you for a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone - I found that after realizing that when I did your code, I was off by 8 hours (the number of hours I'm off from UTC).  I presume you're at UTC +/- 2?

Comment: One of the major deficiencies with the `Date` class is that it isn't intrinsically time-zone aware unless you create it from a `Calendar` instance.  This is part of the reason why Java 8 has a new Date API, including the `ZonedDateTime` class.

Comment: I think you didn't have a duplicate after all - I'm writing an answer explaining

Comment: @soong: do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @H.Z. No. After realizing that the `Z` was a literal, I reviewed my code, and realized I was looking at my output wrong (I'm using a scala REPL, and I looked at how it interpreted my DateTime object in my time zone, rather than the original string).  I think Sotirios's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The `S` pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` represents milliseconds, not fractional milliseconds. As such, `8701036` is parsed as `8701036` milliseconds, which adds 8701 seconds to the total date (or timestamp). That is equivalent to the additional 2 hours, 25 minutes, and 1 second you're seeing.

`SimpleDateFormat` doesn't work with fractions of milliseconds. You'll have to parse them out yourself as far as I know.

Comment: How can I parse that?

Comment: @H.Z. Take the `8701036` and do some math to resolve how many milliseconds out of a second it corresponds to.