# String date to GMT date but it is showing EST

Tags: java, android, date

I want this date to be displayed in GMT "01/01/2100"

Expecting result - "Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2100"

Result i am seeing - "Thu Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 2099"

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  try{
       Date myDate = sdf.parse("01/01/2100");
           System.out.println(myDate);

  }
  catch(Exception e){

  }
```

I want the result myDate in GMT time not EST

**Example 2**

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
  try{
       Date myDate = sdf.parse("2010-05-23 09:01:02");

       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
      System.out.println("MYDATE: " +df.format(myDate));

  }
  catch(Exception e){

  }
```

Output: Sun, 23 May 2010, 05:01

Expecting:  Sun, 23 May 2010, 09:01

http://goo.gl/uIy9RQ  - URL for my project code, run and check the result

Comment: You need to print it through the `SimpleDateFormatter`, not just use `Date.toString()`, which will always use the JVM's default timezone.

Comment: After this code i need to check if the hours and minutes are 00:00:00 But from the above i got 19:00:00 and the logic failing

Comment: Try the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone)

Comment: I tried everything check and run my java code here - http://goo.gl/uIy9RQ

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments you have to apply the date format to the `Date`. I modified your code to display the `myDate`

```
try{
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
     Date myDate = sdf.parse("01/01/2100");
     System.out.println(sdf.format(myDate));
     sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
     System.out.println(sdf.format(myDate));
}
catch(Exception e){
     // error handling
}
```

Output is

```
01/01/2100
31/12/2099
```

But do not forget the date still contains information about hours, minutes, seconds etc. In respect to the applied date formatter this information is not shown when running

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(myDate));
```

If you need to set some fields of the date, you should make use of the [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: Yes, it does as you are not using `sdf.format(myDate)` to print the date to the console.

Answer (score 0):

For customizing date format use below

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Date format parameter can be any one of the following

```
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"-------------------- 010704120856-0700
"K:mm a, z" ----------------------- 0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ---- 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"------- Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"h:mm a" -------------------------- 12:08 PM
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ---------------- Wed, Jul 4, '01
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" ----------- 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
```

Answer (score 0):

## `toString` on java.util.Date Is Misleading

As has been stated many times before on Stack Overflow, the `toString` method of java.util.Date silently applies the JVM’s current default time zone when generating the textual representation of the date-time value. An unfortunate design choice.

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. In Java 8 and later, use the built-in java.time framework. Defined by JSR 310, extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## UTC

Basically [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the same as GMT in this context.

## java.time

The java.time framework includes the class `LocalDate` for a date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone.

Note that getting the current date requires a time zone even though no time zone is stored internally. For any given moment the date varies around the world by time zone, with a new day dawning earlier in the east.

Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Never use 3-4 letter codes such as `EST` as they are neither standardized nor unique.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

The `LocalDate::toString` method generates a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: 2016-01-23.

## Joda-Time

If Java 8 technology is not available to you, add the very successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Joda-Time inspired the java.time.

In this case the code is similar that seen above.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( zone );
```